# How to get input data constantly from the internet

Tags: .htaccess

I want my program to access forex trading data such as market price etc from the internet every minute. I am not sure how my program will access such that or if there is website where such data is provided. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will not find real-time forex data for free (only delayed series). Usually, the data provider is offering an API and an API key, and using a cronjob/task scheduler or some other method you populate your tables by communicating with that API.

Also, a cronjob can't run more often than once per minute, so keep that in mind.